# Best way to represent a grid layout

Tags: css, frameworks, grid

I've a grid design like bellow, can you guys give me a hint about the best way to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with CSS Grid:

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="div1"> </div>
<div class="div2"> </div>
<div class="div3"> </div>
<div class="div4"> </div>
<div class="div5"> </div>
<div class="div6"> </div>
<div class="div7"> </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
grid-column-gap: 0px;
grid-row-gap: 0px;
}

.div1 { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 4; }
.div2 { grid-area: 1 / 4 / 2 / 6; }
.div3 { grid-area: 2 / 4 / 3 / 6; }
.div4 { grid-area: 3 / 4 / 4 / 5; }
.div5 { grid-area: 3 / 5 / 4 / 6; }
.div6 { grid-area: 4 / 4 / 5 / 6; }
.div7 { grid-area: 2 / 1 / 5 / 4; }
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/bzfkduqj/3/)

Comment: Thank you! But what about internet explorer?

Comment: @user3786081 use prefix https://jsbin.com/howuturama/1/edit?html,css,js,output  , a search on SO or on your favorite search engine will give you plenty of ressource ..